# Overloading operator ^ for integer type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operators, operator-overloading

I wrote an application in which I often use `pow` function from `math.h` library. I tried to overload `operator^` to make exponentiation easier and faster. I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int operator^(int, int); // line 6    
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) { /* ... */ }

int operator^(int a, int n)   // line 21
{
  return pow(a,n);
}
```

Compiler (I used g++ on Linux) returned me these errors:

> main.cpp:6:23: error: ‘int operator^(int, int)’ must have an argument
>   of class or enumerated type main.cpp:21:27: error: ‘int operator^(int,
>   int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type

Comment: As codaddict says, you can't overload operators on built-in types, but even if you could, you might well not want to. ^ as bitwise xor is left-associative, so `2^3^4` would mean (2^3)^4 = 4096, rather than the more usual 2^(3^4) ~= 2.4E24.

Comment: @PhilipC: if you're talking about powers, writing `2^3^4` without brackets is a bad idea no matter what the associativity is. Every coder that doesn't know associativity rules by heart will doubt what it actually does.

Comment: Oh... It's one of the main rules in operators overloading and I forgot about it. What a fail :/

Comment: @KillianDS True, but if you were going to make an assumption about which way it was intended, you'd probably assume in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot overload an operator to operate **only on built-in types**.

At least one of the arguments must be a user-defined class or enumerated type (or a reference to one of those) as clearly stated in the compiler error message.

Answer (score 6):

> I tried to overload operator^ to make exponentiation easier and faster

You misspelled **confusing**, because it certainly isn't faster nor easier. **Anyone** maintaining your code will hate you if you did this.

Fortunately, C++ requires at least one parameter be a user-defined type, so you can't do this.

Comment: But even for a user-defined type, it would be a poor choice. `^` is left associative with relatively low precedence. For exponentiation, it should be right associative with extremely high precedence.

Comment: Even for a user-defined type, `^` would be confusing, since it already has a different defined semantics.  For a user defined type, you could use `**` or `^*` (with unary `*` returning a helper class which defined `*` or `^` to mean `pow`), but you'd still have the issues of precedence and binding raised by Jerry.  And using additional helper classes to solve those would mean that parentheses couldn't override the precedence, which is totally unacceptable.